# modalbox height offset browser height in jqmodal?

Tags: jqmodal

can someone point me or give a hint, solution on how to modify a modal box which the height are offset to the browser height resolution?

currently if I have a modal box height of 500px by 1200px and my browser is 1280x1024, the modalbox is not scrolling and cannot view the under parts of the box.

I hope you can help me, thank you

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to set the modal width/height as a percentage of the viewport (e.g. browser window)?

You can do this with CSS providing width and height of html/body are set to 100% first.

As an example, a modal sized to 50% of the viewport and fixed to the center would look like;

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

  #modal { 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 50%;

    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    margin-top: -25%; 
    margin-left: -25%;

    /* display: none; */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="modal">
        <h1>modal</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```